# Distinguishing literal \n vs embedded newline

Tags: antlr4

I am working on validating the Rust parser's handwritten stuff against a model written in antlr. I am hitting a problem with antlr escaping strings for me:

```
[15:48:50]~/src/rust2/src/grammar> grun RustLexer tokens -tokens                                                                               
"\n"
[@0,0:3='"\n"',<46>,1:0]
```

and

```
[15:51:15]~/src/rust2/src/grammar> grun RustLexer tokens -tokens
"
"
[@0,0:2='"\n"',<46>,1:0]
```

Create the same string content. Is there a way for antlr to behave in any other way here? In particular, it would be acceptable if it escaped literal `\` to `\\`, I could then collapse those down in my tool. As it stands, I am losing information about the input.

Comment: I suppose it's just an issue with the debug print where probably the `\\` is not escaped itself. It should be fine in the code behind, e.g. Java or C#. Have you tried this?

Comment: As you can see, the range is longer for the first case (0:3) as opposed to (0:2), so it should really only be a debug print issue. But you could raise an issue at github anyway.

Comment: I don't know what to try, all I've used is the grun tool. If there is something I can do manually to print in a different way, that is fine as well.

Comment: I don't think you can fix the grun output, but the problem should not occur in a "real" application that uses the antlr parser in a e.g. Java or C# project. If you plan to just use grun, you'll have to raise an issue at github and wait for the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grun` is probably doing the expanding of `"\n"`to a line break, because the lexer surely won't do this (luckily).

Given the grammar `Test`:

```antlr
grammar Test;

parse
 : .*? EOF
 ;

LINE_BREAK
 : '\n'
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

that parses `"\n\\n"`:

```java
TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("\n\\n"));

for (Token token : lexer.getAllTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%s -> <%s>%n", TestLexer.ruleNames[token.getType() - 1], token.getText());
}
```

which will print the following:

```
LINE_BREAK -> <
>
OTHER -> <\>
OTHER -> <n>
```

B.t.w., I presume you are aware of [this repository](https://github.com/jbclements/rust-antlr/blob/master/Rust.g4)?

Comment: As to rust-antlr, yes, I'm working on updating that, but I need to verify the lexer separately to handle macro expansion correctly later. In short, it's complicated :). No, my shell is not expanding "\n" to a line break, the shell isn't even involved here, that's just stdin to grun.

I'll take a closer look at the runtime API and how I can use that to get what I want, thanks for the code snippet!